# Eclipse Oxygen: Key shortcut doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

[Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1, Windows 7]

I want to add a shortcut like this for comparing the current file:
[image]

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> on the file doesn't do anything.

But: when I rightclick on the file (like that)
[image]

it shows the shortcut on the function ('Compare with ...'), so the shortcut has been assigned. Clicking on it will show me the Compare windows as expected.
The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> however fails.

Is this a Eclipse Oxygen bug?

It worked fine with Eclipse Mars. There are no conflicts for that shortcut.

Comment: Was the file selected and focused when you pressed Ctrl+Shift+Q or was the focus set to an editor? In the first screenshot, if you click the _Filters..._ button, disable all filters and search for `Ctrl+Shift+Q` instead of `Compare With`, which Ctrl+Shift+Q commands will be shown and with which _When_ condition? If you click Ctrl+Shift+L, is your command in the list?

Comment: Yes, the file was selected and focused (both in Package Explorer and Project Explorer), when I pressed Ctrl+Shift+Q. 
I just disabled all Filters (-> Apply -> Apply and Close). The shortcut still doesn't work. But: when I reopen the 'Keys' dialog, search for my shortcut and go to the filters dialog again, all filters are ENABLED again! Eclipse forgot my selection.

Comment: After disabling all filters do not close the preferences dialog before searching for `Ctrl+Shift+Q`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the When: to "In Package Explorer"

Comment: There's no "In Package Explorer" in the When dropdown.

I have (alphabetically listed): ... In Memory View | In Server View | In Table ...